# Can't get any data in controller that sent from ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, laravel

I have a route,

```
Route::post('/shop', 'ShopController@index');
Route::resource('/shop', 'ShopController')->parameters(['shop' => 'slug']);
```

I want to filter products via price range.

this is my :

```
filter_data();
        var sliderrange = $('#slider-range');
        var amountprice = $('#amount');
        function filter_data() {
            var  min_price = $("#min_price").val();
            var  max_price = $("#max_price").val();
            console.log(min_price);
            $.ajax({ url:"/shop", method:"POST",
                data:{ min_price:min_price, max_price:max_price,},
                success:function (data) { },
            });
        };
```

and this is the controller:

```
    public function index(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->input('min_price');
    print_r($data);

}
```

in the view this is return an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

You've called two post metho which url is /shop

```
Route::post('/shop', 'ShopController@index'); // this is method index
Route::resource('/shop', 'ShopController') //this called store method.
```

So when you call `/shop` method it call store method of ShopController.

Remove `Route::post('/shop', 'ShopController@index');` and use store method.

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->input('min_price');
    print_r($data);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**this method use to get all data**

```
   public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        print_r($data);

    }
```

Comment: return me an empty array

Answer (score 0):

In Js:

```
  var  min_price = $("#min_price").val();
    var  max_price = $("#max_price").val();
    $.ajax({
        url:"/shop_get",
        method:"POST",
        data:{
          "min_price":min_price,
          "max_price":max_price,
          "_token":"{{csrf_token()}}"
        },
        success:function(response){
             console.log(response);
        },
       error:function(errors){
             console.log(errors);
        }
    });
```

In Controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($request->all());

    }
```

In Route:

```
Route::post('/shop_get', 'ShopController@index');
```